# Static delegates and override

Tags: c#, static-members

In one of my many attemts to find a good solution to static override in C# (it´s easy in objective-C, so don´t tell me that "it´s impossible", or that "only objects are polymorphic" because I know) I tried an approach with delegates. My code is:

```
public class Animal
{
    public static Func<string> Name { get; protected set; }

    static Animal()
    {
        Name = () => "Animal";
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    static Cat ()
    {
        Name = () => "Cat";
    }
}
```

But when I call `Cat.Name()` I still get "Animal". I am not asking for a solution, I am asking: why?

Comment: 1) There is only one instance of the field `Animal.Name`. There is no separate `Cat.Name`. `Cat.Name` and `Animal.Name` will always return the same value, either `Cat` or `Animal` depending on which static constructor was the most recent to run. 2) The static constructor hasn't run yet, so it's still returning the old name. The static constructor only runs when you access a member of `Cat` (or construct an instance of it), which `Animal.Name` isn't, even when accessed through `Cat`.

Comment: I'd solve your original problem with a mix of reflection and generics. Generics classes will have a distinct static field for each type.

Comment: That is a great idea, do you suggest replacing a class scheme with something like `Animal<Cat>`, `Animal<Dog>`, ...?

Comment: I wouldn't make `Animal` itself generic, but I'd use a nested class like `Animal.ClassInfo<T>` to access per-class data. Then use reflection to find a static method on `Cat which fills `Animal.ClassInfo<Cat>`.

Comment: I usually avoid reflection since I mostly develop for iOS. But I got it with your advice! Code is not short enough to post it here, and encapsulation is poor... but it´s somehow static overriden!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is only one instance of the field `Animal.Name`. There is no separate `Cat.Name`.

   This implies that `Cat.Name` and `Animal.Name` will always return the same value, either `Cat` or `Animal` depending on which static constructor was the most recent to run.
2. The static constructor hasn't run yet, so it's still returning the old name. The static constructor only runs when you access a static member of `Cat` (or construct an instance of it). `Cat.Name` isn't a member of `Cat` in this sense, since it's actually `Animal.Name`.

   The specifications says about when to run static constructors:

   > The static constructor for a closed class type executes at most once in a given application domain. The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain:
   >   · An instance of the class type is created.
   >   · Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inheritance of static methods in .NET. In terms of IL, `Cat.Name` does not exist, however .NET allows you to call the base class' method from the subclass.
That explains why the static `Cat` constructor is never called.

As `Name` is a method of `Animal` and *not* of Cat, `Animal.Name` is triggered and hence, `Animal's` constructor will be run. The result: you're an animal, not a cat.

[.NET Static Constructors on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)